# In Jupyter, how to avoid extra command lines at bottom of notebook?

Tags: user-interface, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Symptom looks like this:
[View of what the extra lines look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJiTo.png)

After iterating on a single line while developing, clicking 'Alt-Enter' to execute, the console accumulates these extra lines.
Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

select the cell you want to delete-

press the escape button on your keyboard and then press D repeatedly (while escape is pushed down)

Comment: Thank you, I know how to delete them one at a time. I'm curious to know if there is a way to delete them all at once or, better, prevent them from being created in the first place.

Comment: use shift and down arrow to select everything and then delete? I'm not aware of a single command that does this.

Comment: @rbryan - Just tried it - works for me. Maybe you aren't selecting it the way jupyter notebook expects. Select isnt the right word - you need to "highlight" the cell by clicking outside the edit window of the cell. Hope this helps